# Why are all the Xbox 360 games on xbox one "Bundle Only"?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one

**Sadly no, I don't own an Xbox 360**

So I just downloaded the windows 10 Xbox one update, and obviously this contains the backwards compatibility for Xbox 360 games. So I go to the Xbox store to find out all Xbox 360 games are "Bundle Only".

Does this mean I have to buy them from a game store or do I need to own an Xbox 360?

Comment: You should be able to buy them on the website? Don't think it indicates there whether they're backwards compatible or not.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that later

Comment: Could you give examples? I am not sure what you mean by "Bundle Only".

Comment: By bundle only means I can't buy it separately from the Xbox store. Pressing the button brings me to a page on the store which says there are no bundles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update:

Xbox 360 backwards compatible games are now able to be purchased via an Xbox One console in the game marketplace.  All Games with Gold free monthly games are available to download directly from the Games with Gold advertisement on the main screen of the dashboard.  Also, all backwards compatible games already purchased through the Xbox 360 can be found in the "Ready to Install" section at the far right side in the "Games" tab of "Games and Apps".

<strike>You can only purchase titles that are backwards compatible through the xbox.com website or via an Xbox 360 console.  For example, if you are an Xbox Live Gold member, you can go to xbox.com/discounts and "purchase" the free monthly Xbox 360 games.  As soon as you purchase those games on the website, you can go to your "Games and Apps" section on your Xbox One and download the new game through the "Ready to Install" section at the far right side of "Games and Apps".</strike>

Comment: That sounds right, so I'm going to upvote, but it would help to have some evidence of some sort.